# How to reconstruct an object from byte[] not created from ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: java

I need to reconstruct an object on the client side from a `byte[]` which stores bytes coming from an `InputStream`(TCP/IP). The Server is in C and structures are sent across as bytes. It is from these series of bytes that I have to reconstruct the object.

I can do this by reading chunks of bytes and converting them to variables of the object I want to reconstruct, but this method is tedious and I was wondering if there is an easy way out?

Comment: What it wasn't constructed from is irrelevant. The question is what it *was* constructed from. If as you say it was C structs, there are no objects at all to be reconstructed. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna).  You'll have to dig around a bit.  JNA is designed to map C shared libraries (.DLL, .so, etc.) into Java.  But it has various helper classes and methods that can be used to map a C structure in memory to a Java object of similar structure.  I am almost 100% certain you could read these structures off the wire, write the bytes into a ByteBuffer (direct or otherwise), and then map a Java object over them.

Answer (score 2):

> But this method is tedious and I was wondering if there is an easy way out?

Not that I'm aware of. But if you find yourself writing the same code multiple times, you may well find that if you extract some helper methods it actually becomes pretty simple. Yes, you'll need to call a method to read each field value... but the code should end up being easy to read and understand, and not rely on anything magical.

You *could* do all of this with reflection, possibly using annotations to specify the order in which fields have been serialized etc. But that's likely to be a lot of code to write - unless you've got a lot of different types to deserialize, it will probably be more code - and more *complicated* code - than the "dumb but straightforward" approach.

I hope the format of the bytes from the C side of things is well-specified though: if it's basically just dumping the in-memory representation, that can end up being pretty fragile in the face of change.

Comment: C side of things is well taken care of, it just uses memcpy() to reconstruct the structure. But it IS taking a lot of effort to write the equivalent of it on JAVA. Well I was hoping to save the time and the effort... But thanks anyways!

Comment: @user2699116: That doesn't sound like "well taken care of" to me. That sounds like "very fragile" - leading to problems if the data structure changes at all, or the compiler decided to change the field layout, or you move to an architecture with a different endianness etc. Also note that the language/platform is called Java, not JAVA. The latter always sounds shouty.

Comment: Use memcpy() to recreate the structure from data sent over the  network sounds to me like the server was done by a bunch of ignorant  idiots - excuse the harsh words.

Comment: @Ingo - what do you mean? Why cant we use memcpy() in this case?

Comment: @user2699116 because endian-ness may differ ebtween servers, and struct layout between compilers and architectures.